# Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi 3 SPI driver isn't available

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, golang

I have Golang program for Raspberry Pi 3 that reads data using SPI.

I use this library to do that: https://github.com/kidoman/embd. And it works ok on Raspbian OS.
I tried to port it to Ubuntu Core. 
And I am getting an error:

```
/dev/spidev0.0: no such file or directory
```

Is it possible to use *spidev* on Ubuntu Core?

I have tried enabling SPI, as I thought that was an issue. I have added spi=on to **config.txt** file on system-boot partition. But this didn't help. 
Is that an correct way?